# my laptop screen has 2 black horizontal lines on the top of the screen

Tags: laptop, display

my laptop screen has 2 black horizontal lines on the top of the screen please help thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: what do you need help with? ... what's your question?

Comment: Looks like the screen is damaged.

Comment: As @DrMoishePippik points out, your LED screen is damaged.  The black lines might come and go but make no mistake, it is not software.